# params undefined is not an object in route react native

Tags: react-native

I have created a component listing detail screen and listitem in list item it has a card when person click on card it display listingDetailScreen same happen when click suddenly I want to make a bottom tab navigator and in bottom tab navigator I have passed component listing details but it through an error undefined is not an object here is my code of list screen
this prams give me no error in stack navigator but it shows error in tab navigator

```js
const listings = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Close your eyes",
    price: 10,
    image: require("../assets/child.png"),
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "dare to surrender",
    price: 15,
    image: require("../assets/blur.png"),
  },
];
export default function ListingsScreens({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <ExpoScreen style={styles.screen}>
      <FlatList
        data={listings}
        keyExtractor={(listings) => listings.id.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <CardList
            title={item.title}
            subtitle={"$" + item.price}
            image={item.image}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ListingDetails", item)}
          />
        )}
      />
    </ExpoScreen>
  );
}
```

here is my `Screendetailscreen`

```js
export default function ListingDetailsScreen({ route }) {
  console.log(route);
  const listing = route.params;
  return (
    <View style={styles.Screen}>
      <View style={styles.card}>
        <Image style={styles.CardImage} source={listing.image} />

        <View style={styles.tittleContainer}>
          <AppText style={styles.title}>{listing.title}</AppText>
          <AppText style={styles.subtitle}>{listing.price}</AppText>
        </View>
      </View>
      <ListItem
        image={require("../assets/dummyFemale.png")}
        title="Anna bella"
        sutitle="suck 5 person blood"
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

In this I have made a tab navigator

```js
    const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
    const AppNavigation = () => (
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Feed" component={FeedNavigator} />
        <Tab.Screen name="ListingEdit" component={ListingDetailsScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Account" component={AccountNavigator} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    );
```

[image]
this is my console params is undefined but in stack its not undefined in tab it gives undefined

```js
Object { "key": "ListingEdit-oK0Wojum1iGcbBIxCnxNV", "name": "ListingEdit", "params": undefined, }

export default AppNavigation;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In stack navigation you are passing the item like below

```
onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ListingDetails", item)}
```

But the tab navigation you are not passing anything, but you can pass an initial param like below

```
  <Tab.Screen name="ListingEdit" component={ListingDetailsScreen} initialParams={item}/>
```

Where the item is a variable in AppNavigation function.